# Is there a way to access the address of instance variable of any class in C#?

Tags: c#, class

How can i access address of a instance of any class in C# ?Else, is there any utility to for the same ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

```
myClass obj = new myClass();
TypedReference tr = __makeref(obj);
IntPtr ptr = **(IntPtr**)(&tr);
```

Comment: Probably totally unsafe because the GC could "move" the `obj` in memory at any point of time... :-)

Comment: yes, it is unsafe.should be within the unsafe block.

Comment: I want to get address of instances of class created in C#. Is there any method /approach for the same ?